# How to compile only used resources

Tags: android, compiler-construction, builder

Since a while, I'm using a library project containing a lot of reusable code. This way if there's a bug, I have to fix it on only one place. This project also contains a bunch of resources. It's not really a problem that it contains all this stuff, since in most projects I use almost all of them.

Now I'm working on a very small project, and I also use my library project. But I only need some small parts of it, and I had the idea that the java compiler was smart enough to know what classes and resources I needed. Well, that was until I saw the filesize of the complete package... After some decompiling I discovered that all the resources from my library project, which aren't used, are also compiled into the apk.

So now my question is, is there a way to tell the android compiler that it should ignore the resources that aren't used?

Comment: I am also at a point where I wish the tool chain would automatically discard unused resources from linked Android library projects. It's not really straightforward to do that manually in such a case and Lint doesn't help either. I do not want to cripple or create reduced copies of my libraries. Here is a feature request on Android's issue tracker website: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25254

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a tool like [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/). Among other things, it has the ability to detect unused classes, fields etc, resulting in smaller package size.

An excerpt from its feature set:

> [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) is a free Java class file shrinker, optimizer, obfuscator, and preverifier. It detects and removes unused classes, fields, methods, and attributes. It optimizes bytecode and removes unused instructions. (...)

Edit: There is also an optimizer specialized for Android, called [DeXGuard](http://www.saikoa.com/dexguard).

Comment: Thanks for the tip about Proguard. I've tried it out a while ago, but I discovered it did not remove unused images, just the references to it in the R class. What I would like to achieve is that also the images will be deleted then, if it's possible...

Comment: For removal of unused resources, try to use the [Android Lint](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint) tool.

Comment: Lint only gives a warning when there's an unused resource. It doesn't remove them from the apk. (Or did I miss something somewhere?)
And since I'm working with a library project that I use in multiple apps, I can't just delete resources in it.